# How to use back option in flutter programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling a method and trying to go back after the transections is done. But the code doesn't work. Here is what I am trying,

```
onPressed: (){
     _updateResult(context);
},

void _updateResult(BuildContext context) async{
     // some api calls and checks goes here 
     Navigator.of(context).pop();
 }
```

This is how I visit to a page

```
Navigator.push(context, SlideLeftRoute(page: EnterResult(item)));
```

I have a custom class `SlideLeftRoute`

```
class SlideLeftRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
 final Widget page;
  SlideLeftRoute({this.page})
  : super(
      pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      ) =>
          page,
      transitionsBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child,
      ) =>
          SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: const Offset(1, 0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          ),
    );
 }
```

THE PROBLEM CODE

I have found which code creates problems. Here I was calling another method for showing dialogue. if I comment the code it works

```
  void _showMsg(msg) {
   // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
          content: new Text(msg,
          style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontFamily: 'Lato',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
          ),
          //content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );

   }
```

So here after the api call is done, it should go to the back screen but nothing happening.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add how did you came to this screen.
I mean the code for navigation to current widget

Comment: Please see now. I edited my question

Comment: I checked. It did called the code but nothing happened.

Comment: Add debugger and see if your code reach `Navigator.of(context).pop()` maybe you API call never resolved and you probably using `await`

Comment: Add your API calls so we can see what happens exactly

Comment: Nope, it does. I have these lines 
` print('result inserted go back now');
    Navigator.pop(context);
    print(context);`

and I am getting output like this 

`
flutter: result inserted go back now
flutter: EnterResult(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#61914]], state: _EnterResultState#3744b)`

Comment: Let me see. seems api calls problem. I commented the code now it works. but the code were executed after the api codes.

Comment: Please the edited question. It seems my dialogue code is creating problem. Otherwise it goes back.

Comment: Ok it works this way. I need to add back code first then dialogue code. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because when you call `Navigator.of(context).pop();` from the action of an alert `AlertDialog`, it will pop the presented dialog. You have to pop your screen again. For that you can use future returning by `showDialog` method.

That is change your `_showMsg` method like following.

Note the `then(..)...` on `showDialog`

```dart
void _showMsg(msg) async {
    // flutter defined function
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext localContext) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
          content: new Text(
            msg,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 14.0,
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            ),
          ),
          //content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () async {
                print("poping");
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((value) {
      print("poping from screen");
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
  }
```